# Sending argument to Fragment from Activity using NavigationComponent and SafeArgs with the same name reference

Tags: android, android-xml, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-safe-args

I have a case here that I have to open a Fragment from an Activity and I did it sometimes but the issue here that I wanna open the Fragment that has an argument with it.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/productDetailsFragment"
    android:name="com.a.ry.ui.product.ProductDetailsFragment"
    android:label="fragment_product_details2"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_product_details" >
    <argument
        android:name="productId"
        app:argType="integer" />
</fragment>
```

What I know is that I can open a Fragment (From Activity) and pass its Argument like this:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putInt("productId", productIdValue)
navController.navigate(R.id.productDetailsFragment, bundle)
```

the problem is here **"productId"**
what if another developer change that name from navigation.xml file so it's not the best practice at all

I want to take the same reference of that argument name.

Or if there is another solution for that?

Comment: SafeArgs plugin generates a special Direction class for each action. You should use this class.

Answer (score 0):

You should define it in string.xml and use in XML and code.

```
android:name="@string/VAR"

 getString (R.string.VAR);
```

Comment: no bro, navigation generated class will understand  @string/VAR as a name